# Meaning of “a hoot, a mess, a handful”

Tags: meaning

A guy said to me:

> You are a hoot, girl; a mess, a handful.

What does it mean, please? Is it a good or a bad? What is its meaning in context?

Comment: More context please!  What is the relationship of the guy to you? How well does he know you?  What were you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a good or a bad?

It is whatever you wish it to be, offense cannot be given, it can only be taken. If someone says to you "you have a strong personality", then it is your choice to be upset or be happy about it.

> A guy said to me: "you are a hoot, girl; a mess, a handful”. What does it mean, please?

The separate parts are largely slang and can mean:

- a hoot: this generally means funny, someone who you enjoy spending time with.
- a mess: this generally means disorganized and aren't on a set life path or haven't planned things.  This doesn't really fit into the context of the sentence and so likely the person saying it either doesn't know what it means or didn't think too hard about it.
- a handful: this means a strong personality with opinions, someone who is not easy to control.  Another phrase along this line would be 'high maintenance'.